# How can scroll a div use GeckoFX and C#

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I want to scroll a div via Gecko and C#

My code is

```
GeckoDivElement div1 = new GeckoDivElement(icdIFrameElement.ContentDocument.GetHtmlElementById("t1::scroller").DomObject);
GeckoElementCollection divs = div1.GetElementsByTagName("div");
GeckoDivElement div = new GeckoDivElement(divs[0].DomObject);
div.ScrollIntoView(true);
div.ScrollTop += 10;
```

but it does not work.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. My code is correct but to works I used theads and delegates.
So I found below solution

```
public delegate void geckoWebBrowserDelegate();

public void scrollWithTheads()
{
   Thread oThread = new Thread(new geckoWebBrowserDelegate(scrollWithThread));
   oThread.Start();
}

private void scrollWithThread()
{
  _myGeckoWebBrowser.Invoke("scroll");
}

private void scroll()
{
 GeckoDivElement div1 = new  GeckoDivElement(_myGeckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("t1::scroller").DomObject);
 GeckoElementCollection divs = div1.GetElementsByTagName("div");
 GeckoDivElement div = new GeckoDivElement(divs[0].DomObject);
div.ScrollIntoView(true);
div.ScrollTop += 10;
}
```